# Take snapshot using Selenium for page that doesn't stop loading

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to capture screenshots of a web page. It works great on sites like stackoverflow but I'm trying to use it on a page that never stops loading. Is there a way to grab the screenshot after x seconds regardless if it's done or not?

Current code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()


    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for url in f.readlines():

            driver.get('http://' + url)

            sn_name = os.path.join('Screenshots', url.strip().replace('/', '-') + '.png')

            print('Attempting to save:', sn_name)
            if not driver.save_screenshot(sn_name):
                raise Exception('Could not save screen shot: ' + sn_name)

    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What happens when `trying to use it on a page that never stops loading`?

Comment: Nothing, it just waits for the page to stop loading so it can take a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't work like that. 
Webdriver will implicit waiting for a page loading till timed-out. 
It should give you a timeout exception. 
I think you should use try-except to catch that and then take a screenshot.
Otherwise, you should do a multithreading programming for another thread to take a screenshot.

Comment: Any chance you have some pseudo code for that? I am completely new to python

Comment: You can also reduce (or extend) the page load timeout according to your desire. Regarding multithreading, I don't believe that it's gonna work as webdriver is not thread safe, and that might lead to race conditions. Creating another instance of webdriver is also not an option as it will open a new browser instance, so you won't be able to take a screenshot of the first browser from it.